# Click event on icon within div which is also clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have divs that serve as a dropdown button when they are clicked. I also have a trash icon for if the user wants to remove each item from the list. What I am trying to do is to remove the whole div item from the page if the trash icon is clicked.

I have tried accessing the icon with an click event, but it still drops down the div.

```html
<div class="collapsible btn-collaps text-center valid-files collapsed"
aria-expanded="false"
data-target="#a1"
data-toggle="collapse">
<i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg float-left remove"
aria-hidden="true"></i>
test.txt</div>


<div class="collapse" id="a1">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">Sub value</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">sub value 2</li>
        <li class="list-group-item">sub value 3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```
$(".remove").on('click', function(e){
    alert('test');
});
```

However this does not alert the page "test". It also doesn't work if I do

```
$(".valid-files").on('click', function(e){
    alert('test');
});
```

What I eventually want to do is delete the clickable div along with the corresponding div containing the list when the trash icon is clicked. I think I can manage that part on my own, nut I am not sure how to access the click event of the icon. Does anybody have any ideas?

As a side note, there could be multiple divs which have the classes `collapsible btn-collaps text-center valid-files collapsed`, and multiple corresponding divs with the `collapse` class.

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). There's no reason your `.remove` handler shouldn't work unless the elements don't exist yet, in which case [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements). (Either way, you'll probably need `e.stopPropagation();` or `return false;`)

Comment: use e.stopPropagation() for .remove

Answer (score 0):

The width of `i` is very negligible so when ever you was clicking, the click was on the parent dom. I believe with real icon this wont be the case.

Secondly you can use `parent` and `remove` function to remove the element from the dom

```js
$(".valid-files").on('click', '.remove', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().remove();
  $("#a1").remove();
});
$(".valid-files").on('click', function(e) {});
```

```css
.remove {
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="collapsible btn-collaps text-center valid-files collapsed" aria-expanded="false" data-target="#a1" data-toggle="collapse">Div Content
  <i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg float-left remove" aria-hidden="true">test.txt</i>
</div>


<div class="collapse" id="a1">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li class="list-group-item">Sub value</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">sub value 2</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">sub value 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```